# Prevent shadowing of Ok and Error with FParsec?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a test like this:

```ml
module MyTests

open Xunit
open FParsec
open FsUnit.Xunit
open MyParsers

[<Fact>]
let ``pfoo works as expected`` () =
  let text = "blahblahblah"

  let actual =
    match run pfoo text with
    | Success (x, _, _) -> Result.Ok x
    | Failure (s, _, _) -> Result.Error s

  let expected : Result<Foo, string> =
    Result.Ok
      {
        Foo = "blahblahblah"
      }

  expected
  |> should equal actual
```

`open FParsec` will shadow `Ok` so that I need to fully qualify it like `Result.Ok`.

This is pretty annoying. Is there a good way to "open" `Result` again so that I can write `Ok` unqualified?

Answer (score 4):

It's not `Result` that you need to "open", but `Microsoft.FSharp.Core`, which is the module in which `Result` and both its constructors are defined. This module is open by default, but you can open it again to have its definitions closer in the scope:

```
open Xunit
open FParsec
open FsUnit.Xunit
open MyParsers
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core
```

---

Alternatively, you can alias just the `Ok` identifier:

```
let Ok = Result.Ok

let x = Ok "foo"  // x : Result<string, _>
```

I prefer this latter method, because it minimizes the impact surface and thus reduces the chance of unexpected surprises.

The downside is that the aliased `Ok` won't work for pattern matching:

```
match x with 
| Ok y -> ... // This is Ok from FParsec
```

If you need pattern matching as well, you'll have to alias the matcher too:

```
let (|Ok|Error|) x = match x with | Result.Ok o -> Ok o | Result.Error e -> Error e
```

At which point I would probably fall back to reopening the module.